# pandas apply() auto add .0 behind of my string

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I am still learning python and new to using panda module. I am trying to combine two columns in a csv consist of IP address and CIDR and output to a text file as e.g: 10.0.0.1/24 and below is my code:

```
import pandas as pd

path = '/Users/myfolder/Downloads/ip.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(path)
df = df[['Address', 'CIDR']].apply(lambda x: '/'.join(x.map(str)), axis=1)
df.to_csv("/Users/myfolder/Downloads/result.txt", header=False, index=False)
```

However, the result has a .0 behind of each line:

`10.0.0.1/24.0 10.0.0.2/24.0 10.0.0.3/24.0`
is there a flag to enable or is there something wrong in the code section that i need to change?

Tried using other concatenate method like merge() or agg() but seems like join() and map() are the closest i can get as the data are not string to begin with.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should first convert to integer, then to string to avoid having floats:

```
out = (df[['Address', 'CIDR']]
      .astype({'CIDR': 'Int64'})
      .apply(lambda x: '/'.join(x.map(str)), axis=1)
      )
```

##### original answer

```
lambda x: '/'.join(x.astype(int).astype(str))
```

Or, if you have NaNs:

```
lambda x: '/'.join(x.astype('Int64').astype(str))
```

Comment: seems like i cant just convert them to int due to the raw data is in float (ip address) because i got this error: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '10.0.0.1'

Comment: Of course, then you should only convert the CIDR column, see update

Comment: @nickee maybe provide a small example of the input for reproducibility?

Comment: thanks, i got work now, just couldn't remove the NaN from the final result with x.astype('Int64'), i end up using drop() as NaN only happen on 1st row. Example input will be: Address column - [empty cell],10.0.0.1, 10.0.1.1, 10.0.2.1 and CIDR column - [empty cell],24,31,18